# Failing to sort pandas dataframe by values in descending order and then alphabetically in ascending order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, alphabetical-sort

A slice of my dataframe, df, is like this, so you can reproduce it.

```
data ={'feature_name': ['nite', 'thank', 'ok', 'havent', 'done', 'beverage', 'yup', 'lei','thanx', 'okie', '146tf150p', 'home', 'too', 'anytime',
       'where', '645', 'er', 'tick', 'blank'], 'values':[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.98, 0.98] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('feature_name',inplace=True)
dfs=df.sort_index(ascending=True).sort_values(by = ['values'], ascending=False)
dfs
```

my output is this.

```
            values
feature_name    
146tf150p   1.00
645         1.00
where       1.00
too         1.00
thanx       1.00
thank       1.00
okie        1.00
ok          1.00
nite        1.00
lei         1.00
home        1.00
havent      1.00
er          1.00
done        1.00
beverage    1.00
anytime     1.00
yup         1.00
blank       0.98
tick        0.98
```

I do not quite understand why it is not like this? It really should work yet it does not work as expected.

```
146tf150p   1.00
645         1.00
anytime     1.00
beverage    1.00
done        1.00
er          1.00
haven't     1.00
home        1.00
...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: because you do a `.sort_values(by = ['values'], ascending=False)` later which adjusts the sort later

Comment: why then something simpler is ok? data ={'feature_name': ["newt","tiger","otter","hamster","deer", "badger", 'tortoise', 'boar'], 'values':[1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.98, 0.98] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.set_index('feature_name',inplace=True)
dfsorted = df.sort_values(by = ['values', 'feature_name'], ascending=False)

Comment: i don't understand what you mean.. may be you can edit your question to be clearer..

Comment: I think what you want is 1. Don't `set_index` to `feature_name` 2. Use `df.sort_values(by = ['values',"feature_name"], ascending=(False, True))`.

Comment: Can you  post your answer as an answer, not in the comments section, so that I could vote for it?

Comment: It works! Henry Yik, you've spotted my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `set_index` and use `sort_values` on both values and feature_name:

```
print (df.sort_values(by = ['values',"feature_name"], ascending=(False, True)))

   feature_name  values
10    146tf150p    1.00
15          645    1.00
13      anytime    1.00
5      beverage    1.00
4          done    1.00
16           er    1.00
3        havent    1.00
11         home    1.00
7           lei    1.00
0          nite    1.00
2            ok    1.00
9          okie    1.00
1         thank    1.00
8         thanx    1.00
12          too    1.00
14        where    1.00
6           yup    1.00
18        blank    0.98
17         tick    0.98
```